# Preventing folders from being moved in Outlook folder list

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office

In the Outlook "folder list", it is quite easy to accidentally pickup a folder and move that into another folder. There is no undo for this, and I have not found a way to prevent this.

I thought it was just me, but I recently saw a coworker do the same thing while filing mail via drag and drop. The behavior is the same using Exchange 2003 and 2007 and Outlook 2007.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still unable to prevent accidentally moving a folder, but there is a better way to locate the folder than opening nearby folders until you find it.

Use the **Folder Size** list to get a list of all folders and subfolders.

In Outlook 2016,

1. In the folder list, right click on the root of the mailbox,
2. Select **Folder Permissions** (or **Properties** depending on Outlook version),
3. On the **General** tab, click the **Folder Size...** button,
4. Scroll down the list of subfolders until you find your missing folder. You can resize the column to let you see longer subfolder names.

Credit to: https://www.msoutlook.info/question/accidentally-moved-a-folder-and-cannot-find-it

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to lock the folders, but in Outlook 2007, you can collapse the folder list so that you don't accidentally drag them. There is a double arrow pointing left at the top of the navigation pane that can be used to collapse or expand the pane.

Comment: That's a good idea when they aren't in use. But most of the time it happens just before or just after actually filing email in the folders.